# How to setup Git Bash (msysgit) with a github token or ssh key

Tags: git, github

New to Git.

Followed all the directions from github [help](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) pages but simple commands like git pull and git push continues to prompt my password on each invocation. Specifically, I set the following:

- git config --global user.name "Your name"
- git config --global user.email you@yourdomain.com
- git config --global github.token 123321321sdssddaqqwq

I also setup ssh keys elaborately as per the steps mentioned in the help but password prompts don't go away.

Suggestions?

Comment: What is the actual prompt? It may actually be a prompt for your passphrase on your SSH key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your comment saying that the password that works at this prompt is your GitHub password, I strongly suspect that you've cloned your repository using the `https` URL rather than the SSH URL.  You can change that with:

```
 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:whoever/whatever.git
```

... where you should replace the last parameter with whatever's shown when you click the "SSH" button on your repository's page.

(You can check what URL `origin` currently refers to with `git remote -v`.)

Comment: No problem.  I thought this was a pretty good catch, though, and not  a single up-vote from *anyone*?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you sign your pub key with a password? If you sign your *key* with a password, you'll always be prompted for *that* key. If you want no password, re-generate your `.pub` file without a password and upload that to github. If anyone gets access to your machine, they can commit as you, of course.

Comment: I regenerated the key without a passphrase and password prompt is still being asked. Note that the password I use to get past this is my github password.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start `ssh-agent`, then use `ssh-add` to add your key. This requires the password once per session. You can also add it to the end of `/etc/bashrc` to add the key automatically on startup.

Better yet, have a simple function to your key to ssh-agent:

```
eval `ssh-agent`;
trap "kill $SSH_AGENT_PID" 0;
add-key {
  ssh-add;
}
```

Comment: I use windows. 
Why are these instructions not in the original github manual?
What's the procedure to use github token as auth credentials?

Comment: This works on windows, given you use msysgit or a cygwin install. Don't ask me about github, I don't use it. What is a github token? You are only prompted for your password if you set up your key with one. I don't know if github assumes passwordless ssh keys …