# Github user login details change

Tags: github

how to change the github login details on a localhost git bash?

I have configure my GitHub repository with my friend's `github.username` and `github.token` at the time of installation, I want to change from that id to my own id.

How should we do that?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, there's no place that you would enter your GitHub password other than in the browser or the GitHub for Mac app.

Comment: sorry that's my mistake in this case i mean to say gitHub.token

Comment: Sooo, edit your question to reflect that?

Comment: To any "moderator" happy to cast a "not a real question" flag, please read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/#comment-65473, especially the sentence "This is especially prevalent for users who are clearly English as second language users. Instead of moderators helping bridge the language barrier they immediately jump for the nuclear option of “not a question”...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two parameters are managed by Git config:

```
$ git config --global github.user username
$ git config --global github.token 0123456789yourf0123456789token
```

If you want to change them just for a project, you can remove the `--global` parameter and repeat that command just in a specific repo.

This [help/setup script](https://github.com/help/setup) illustrates the steps necessary for GitHub authentication.

See also "[How to setup Git Bash (msysgit) with a github token or ssh key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353040/how-to-setup-git-bash-msysgit-with-a-github-token-or-ssh-key)".