# Git error when generating ssh keys

Tags: github

I'm using windows 8 64-bit and the latest version of GIT.
I'm trying to generate ssh keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@domain.com"` but cannot create the key I'm getting an error.

[image: http://content.screencast.com/users/DineshJasti/folders/Jing/media/24c3f3fc-43d6-437b-b1ca-083946afc55b/2013-10-20_2115.png]

I tried giving some name to my key then it gave me an error:

```
could not connect to your authentication agent
```

[image: http://content.screencast.com/users/DineshJasti/folders/Jing/media/8a88fad4-8b1d-40de-9dc7-4c5f9db12f20/2013-10-20_2132.png]

Can some one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh key generation is based on the environment variable HOME.
HOME isn't defined by default.
It is defined only if you start a git session through [git-cmd.bat](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat#L9-L10):

```
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Make sure that `%HOME%` exists, and everything else ssh-related should work just fine.

Comment: Echo home returns home and homepath gives me the user directory.
Screen shot http://screencast.com/t/D50waSfjs

Comment: @DineshJasti your screenshot shows that HOME isn't defined.  My answer stands.

Comment: Tanq VonC excuting this '@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%' solved my problem but I'm unable to add it when I execute 'ssh-add' it says "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent".Any solution plz..

Comment: @DineshJasti are you *sure* you want to manage ssh keys with passphrase? If so, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/7353153/6309 (add a `bashrc` file in `C:\your\path\to\PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916\etc`) to make sure the `ssh-agent` is running.

Comment: Sry for the late reply.Let me give you a overview of my situation I have installed and used GIT in my old laptop and have been using it along with pycharm and Heroku but now I have got a new laptop in which I'm trying to install and use git I have set the global name and email ID and now am trying to create a SSH key to link it with my account my main purpose is to use Heroku and I couldn't get it done coz of all these errors.So,now if u there is any other way plz guide me.And I havent set any pass phrase during the key generation.

Comment: @DineshJasti then you don't need the ssh-add step, nor do you need the ssh agent. For heroku, the guide is https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: I tried it previously but it didn't work then,but it is working now.I need to get GIT working I will be needing it in a few days.

Comment: @DineshJasti It is working now? Great! Don't forget, as long as %HOME% is defined, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes it is working for Heroku but not for GIT and one more strange problem if I give 'git push heroku master' it is giving me an error.But if I give only 'git push' it's working.Any idea how this can be solved and I have a lot of files hosted in my repository how can I pull them from GIT..??Not heroku.
http://screencast.com/t/b5TuMkUdMJ
http://screencast.com/t/AoZdI1wH8el
http://screencast.com/t/X3oaYaMR0s

Comment: @DineshJasti regarding heroku, the guide to follow in order to add new ssh keys that you have generated is https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys.

Comment: I know about that what I want to know is how to get my files that are there in my Github repository...??
'git pull' is not working..

Comment: @DineshJasti can you copy the *text* of the error message in your question? (that you can edit) I cannot access screencast.com at work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your working directory, it seems you are not in the `.ssh` folder. I think that's what is causing the problem.

Github provides an excellent step by step [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows) to create an ssh key and add it later on Github.

Comment: That is the tutorial I have been following and I also tried doing the same from .ssh directory but no change in result.

Comment: Can you `echo %HOMEPATH%` and tell me what it gives you?

Comment: Homepath returns a path to my user directory.
Screen shot http://screencast.com/t/D50waSfjs